# Share USB 3G internet through a router but keep the local network access

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, usb, router, dongle

I'm working on Ubuntu and I was able to share my USB dongle internet through a router by connecting my Ethernet output directly to the WAN port of the router and choosing in IPv4 Setting the Method "Shared to other computers".
Thus all machines connected to the router have now access to internet but I lost local access between them. I also need to access from my Ubuntu workstation to some of the devices connected to the router.

Is that possible?

(working on Ubuntu 12.04)

Netstat -rn output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ppp0
10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
```

and the ifconfig -a output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:44:fd:2e:23:02  
          inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e44:fdff:fe2e:2302/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2008 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:315273 (315.2 KB)  TX bytes:568508 (568.5 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:ef300000-ef320000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:98715 (98.7 KB)  TX bytes:98715 (98.7 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:111.188.200.8  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7785 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6397 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:7711926 (7.7 MB)  TX bytes:648755 (648.7 KB)
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is your 3g dongle connected? Is it connected to a 3G router or shared via some other way?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but by USB dongle I meant a "USB dongle" plugged into the computer.

Comment: Please share your "netstat -rn" and "ifconfig -a" output. May be the route to reach your local network is missing, so you are not able to reach them.

Comment: I edited my question and included the outputs.

Comment: netstat output looks fine. May be you can do a ping test (ping one of the machine behind router) and run tcpdump on your laptop (listen on eth0) and the destination machine, see if the packet goes out on eth0. If yes, then verify whether it reaches the destination system. If you see the packet received on destination, check whether response is sent and check the same in your laptop.

Comment: im sorry but Im not that good with networking under Ubuntu. Is it even possible to be connected on a local network to other machines when my desktop (internet source) ethernet cable is plugged to the WAN input of the router and not the LAN input?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Because the WAN input is for LAN access and the eth0 gateway will be used for that. When you try to connect to the machines in the LAN (i.e packets with DST IP addr as 10.42.*.*) then the packet will see the rule 2 ( as per your netstat output) and use eth0 to send the packet out. When you try to connect to external world, then it will use rule 1 and send packet through ppp0. I think the order may be one possible reason. I am not really sure about it. Can you try to add this route <!-- 10.42.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0 --!> first

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. First, if you want to have connection between all computers of your network, you'll do this by LAN. So, by this, you'll need to connect your pc to the LAN port of your router.

Relating to the configurations in the Ubuntu machine, you'll need to configure the "wired connection" of your LAN port to be Shared to Other Computers. But for this to work, you'll have to disable the DHCP server in your router, so that Ubuntu will be who will assign IP's automatically. Thus:

1. Connect PC to LAN port of router.
2. Disable DHCP server on router.
3. Configure router's connection("Wired Connection #") to method "Shared to Other Computers"

Done. Since this is a LAN, any kind of local access will be enabled, such as local file transfering and VNCs, like TeamViewer. WAN connections don't have versatility as LANs do.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to do this but I still have a problem. DHCP is deactivated. Let's say a laptop is connected via Wireless LAN to the router, it manually set its IP adress to 192.168.1.3 and Netmask is 192.168.1.1 . Now From my workstation I choose "share to other computers" and it will automatically assign a weird IP adress 10.42.0.1 and broadcast adress (is that same as Netmask?) 10.42.0.255. Now how can I access to the main browser page of the router? neither 192.168.1.1 nor 10.42.0.255 work and I can't access to the laptop anymore.